# Restful Authentication -- how to log in a user without password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, restful-authentication

I've got a cross-website integration to handle.  Basically I'm passing a param into the rails application and if it evaluates correctly ... then I'd like to log a user in.

Can this be done without the users password?

something like simply evaluating the password as true?

Comment: you need to login a user into your app or do authorized action within your app?

Comment: I need to log in a user.  So you're suggesting going around restful auth?

Comment: just cannot get what you want to do. If you want to login user without a password you can simply login him\her depending on your authentification system e.g. if you're using 'devise' gem: `sign_in @some_user`. Or you want to use other authorization method with some specific secret key?

Answer (score 1):

This is called "token authentication" and is supported by Devise, or can be relatively easily ginned up on your own. You want to generate a non-guessable secret token (your param), and then use that in lieu of a username. The devise wiki has links to a couple of examples:

https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Simple-Token-Authentication-Example

If you want a lighter-weight solution, you can also simply generate an auth token (using something like bcrypt) and then do something like:

```
@user = User.find_by_auth_token(params[:auth_token])
```

if @user is nil, then return a 403.